# Issue with a static recursive method

Tags: c#, reflection, recursion, static

I am working on a logic where I have populate a composite class instance from a dictionary Key/Value pairs. The composite classes will be marked with attributes which will be mapped against the keys from the dictionary.
One specific requirement is that if class C1 is having a property of type class C2, but there are no pairs in the dictionary for the properties of class C2 to be mapped against then C2 should be set to null. Otherwise if there is at least a single property of C2 which can be mapped, then C2 property of C1 must be instantiated.
I have written a recursive function to implement this logic. The requirement is not working as intended. I am using a flag isInstanceValuePresent which check if at least one of the property of C2 can be mapped. Else, it's false value should tell me that I have to assign null to the C2 property of class C1. If anyone can help me understand why the logic fails and what could be the correct solution, I would very well appreciate that. Following is the static recursive method:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Populates the given instance object with the supplied source dictionary values
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modelInstance">The object whose properties are to be initialized with the data</param>
    /// <param name="source">The source dictionary containing Schema(Keys) and corresponding Values</param>
    private static void PopulateModelInstance(object modelInstance, IDictionary<string, string> source)
    {
        bool isInstanceValuePresent = false;

        foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in modelInstance.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            //Identify Custom attribute 
            DataMappingKeyAttribute attribute = (DataMappingKeyAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(propInfo, typeof(DataMappingKeyAttribute));

            if (attribute != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.MappingKey))
            {
                if (propInfo.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || propInfo.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string)))
                {
                    string sourceKey = attribute.MappingKey;

                    if (source.ContainsKey(sourceKey))
                    {
                        isInstanceValuePresent = true;

                        // Get propInfo attribute value from Dictionary
                        //var propertySourceValue = source[(propInfo.PropertyType.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DataMappingKeyAttribute)) as DataMappingKeyAttribute).MappingKey];
                        string sourceValue = source[attribute.MappingKey];

                        // Set propInfo value on the model instance
                        if (CanChangeType(sourceValue, propInfo.PropertyType) && propInfo.CanWrite && (!propInfo.PropertyType.IsClass || propInfo.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string))))
                            propInfo.SetValue(modelInstance, Convert.ChangeType(sourceValue, propInfo.PropertyType), null);
                    }
                }
            }


            if (propInfo.PropertyType.IsClass && !propInfo.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string)) && propInfo.CanWrite)
            {
                isInstanceValuePresent = false;
                object referenceTypeInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(propInfo.PropertyType);

                PopulateModelInstance(referenceTypeInstance, source);

                if (isInstanceValuePresent == false)
                {
                    propInfo.SetValue(modelInstance, null, null);
                    referenceTypeInstance = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    propInfo.SetValue(modelInstance, referenceTypeInstance, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I even appreciate if someone can help me optimize the function.

Comment: How does the logic fail? does it not execute, or how is your result not as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One major problem with your code is the use of the variable **isInstanceValuePresent**. Before recursively calling **PopulateModelInstance** you set the variable to false and then test the value once the method returns. Unfortunately this variable is a local variable, resides on the stack and as such is local to each call. It won't reflect the value set in your recursive call.

I have a suggestion how you could change your method. Instead of passing in an object to be populated, you could pass in the type of the object to be populated. Using the same logic you have already implemented, you would only instantiate an object of this type if you find a property value that can be set. The method then passes back the instance. If no property has been found to set then the method passes back **null**.

```
private static Object CreateAndPopulateModelInstance(Type modelInstanceType, IDictionary<string, string> source)
{
    // this variable will hold the reference to the instance that is to be
    // populated. It will only hold a value, if a property is found that
    // can be populated.
    Object modelInstance = null;

    foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in modelInstanceType.GetProperties())
    {
        //Identify Custom attribute 
        DataMappingKeyAttribute attribute =  DataMappingKeyAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(propInfo, typeof(DataMappingKeyAttribute));

        if (attribute != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.MappingKey))
        {
            if (propInfo.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || propInfo.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string)))
            {
                string sourceKey = attribute.MappingKey;

                if (source.ContainsKey(sourceKey))
                {
                    // Get propInfo attribute value from Dictionary
                    //var propertySourceValue = source[(propInfo.PropertyType.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DataMappingKeyAttribute)) as DataMappingKeyAttribute).MappingKey];
                    string sourceValue = source[attribute.MappingKey];

                    // Set propInfo value on the model instance
                    if (CanChangeType(sourceValue, propInfo.PropertyType) && propInfo.CanWrite && (!propInfo.PropertyType.IsClass || propInfo.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string))))
                    {
                        // create instance if necessary
                        if (modelInstance == null)
                            modelInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(modelInstanceType);

                        propInfo.SetValue(modelInstance, Convert.ChangeType(sourceValue, propInfo.PropertyType), null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (propInfo.PropertyType.IsClass && !propInfo.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string)) && propInfo.CanWrite)
        {
            Object propertyValue = CreateAndPopulateModelInstance(propInfo.PropertyType, source);
            if (propertyValue != null)
            {
                // create instance if necessary
                if (modelInstance == null)
                    modelInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(modelInstanceType);

                // set property value
                propInfo.SetValue(modelInstance, propertyValue, null);
            }
        }
    }

    return modelInstance;
}
```

I renamed the method to reflect the fact that the object is created (if necessary).
Before a property is set the method checks to see if the modelInstance has already been instantiated, if not an object of the type passed in is instantiated.

If the method passes back **null** you know that your property value couldn't be instantiated because it didn't have any properties that could be initialized. This should work regardless of how deep the recursion goes.

I haven't tested this code (or even compiled it), so there maybe syntax errors in there. The logic ought to be ok.

You'll have to change the initial call to this method, or maybe add a third parameter that initializes the modelInstance variable like this:

```
private static Object CreateAndPopulateModelInstance(Object instance, Type modelInstanceType, IDictionary<string, string> source)
{
    // this variable will hold the reference to the instance that is to be
    // populated. It will only hold a value, if a property is found that
    // can be populated.
    Object modelInstance = instance;
```

The recursive call would then look like this:

```
            Object propertyValue = CreateAndPopulateModelInstance(null, propInfo.PropertyType, source);
            if (propertyValue != null)
            {
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @roadkill, your solution worked perfectly. I really appreciate the efforts you put into explaining the solution.